# how to pass file names from multer to another middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Multer takes the files i upload and puts it inside the file object so we can access it through the file but then the `req.body.image` is empty and i want to be able to pass the `file.originalname` to the `req.body.image` as path to the stored disk location. Now, i am working with multiple file here so i want to store their paths in the req object and access it inside another middle ware.
I tried something like this

```
req.body.image.push(`path/${file.originalname}`)
```

which returns an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

It looks like `req.body.image` isn't an Array but `undefined` when you're using `push()`.

When multer [adds a single file](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#singlefieldname) to the request object, it adds them to the `req.file` property. You can then access `req.file` in subsequent middleware like in the below example. If you have [multiple uploaded files](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount) then you would access the File Array `req.files` and iterate through the collection to access each file object.

In your above code, you're modifying the `req.body` object and adding the property `image`, I wouldn't recommend changing the `req.body` object. It is good practice to not mutate things like the request headers or body. Instead, you can add a new property `req.image` to the request object.

The below example uses Router Middleware to encapsulate the upload logic, (which should be kept to a single route usually) and then adds that middleware to an Express Server.

#### imageUploadRouter.js

```
// imageUploadRouter.js
const router = require('express').Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'})

router.use(upload.single('image'))
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(req.image)) {
    req.image = []
  } 

  if (req.file) {
    req.image.push(`path/${req.file.originalName}`)
  }

  return next()
})

// add some additional routes for logic
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // do something and respond
  // you can access req.image here too
  return res.sendStatus(201)
})

module.exports = router
```

#### server.js

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const ImageUploadRouter = require('./imageUploadRouter')

const server = new Express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337

server.use('/images', ImageUploadRouter)
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Lisening on ${port}`))
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped.